# Calculate Progress Bar Width from Values

Tags: php, html, css

I had tried to have a hunt around for this but I'm not sure how to code the determining width value based on the progress bar values.

Example of progress bar code

```html
<div id="raffle_wise_ticket_bar" title="Sold 139 out of 1399">
  <div class="zero">0</div>
  <div class="progress" style="width: (This is what I need to calculate);">
    <div class="arrow_up" style="border-bottom-color: #ffffff;"></div>
    <div class="purchased" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #000000a3;">139 sold</div>
  </div>
  <div class="full">1399</div>
</div>
```

I have php code which gives me the amount sold, min amount, full amount and just looking for something which can take those values and calculate the width in the  line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of CSS [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()):

```
width: calc(var(--amount-sold) / var(--full-amount) * 100%)
```

Simply replace `var(--amount-sold)` with the amount sold and `var(--full-amount)` with the full amount. `* 100%` is required to convert it to a percentage.

Demo (uses CSS variables for demonstration):

```css
:root{
 --full-amount: 20;
 --amount-sold:10;
}
```

```html
<div id="raffle_wise_ticket_bar" title="Sold 139 out of 1399">
  <div class="zero">0</div>
  <div class="progress" style="width: calc(var(--amount-sold) / var(--full-amount) * 100%)">
      <div class="arrow_up" style="border-bottom-color: #ffffff;"></div>
      <div class="purchased" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #000000a3;">139 sold</div>
    </div>
    <div class="full">1399</div>
  </div>
```